# 1 Column used twice in the visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data model, in which one of the tables has following columns:

| CharacteristicsID | Type | Value | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Country | UK | ... |
| 1 | SalesPerson | Peter | ... |
| 2 | Country | US | ... |
| 2 | SalesPerson | Mark | ... |
| 2 | SalesPerson | John | ... |

What I need to do is to create following pivot table:

[image]

Numbers are coming from another related table, but that's not important now.

My problem is that both Country & SalesPerson are from the same column. Don't you have some smart idea how to solve it? I have possibility to edit source data on all levels.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are mixing country and salesperson in this way if they are actually in a hierarchy? I would have one table with information about country, and another with information about people. Your pivot table requires UK and US to be in a separate column vs. Peter, Mark and John.

Comment: Unfortunately this data structure is coming from source tool = what I get as outcome of ETL process. Both sample ID 1 & 2 have much more rows with other types, not only Country & SalesPerson. Unpivoting in ETL would mean hundreds / tousands of new columns.

Comment: Do you have a staging area? This is the appropriate place to transform you data making it  convenient for OLAP.

Comment: So what you want is based on the order of the table, conclude that Peter is from the UK. with mquery you can manipulate the data to that level but it is not that easy. you first need to add an index, than make 2 seperate tables and do a lookup (function) to bring it back together in one table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posible solution.
My sample excel:

[image]

Add an index column (transofrmation tab):

[image]

Select "Type" column and use "Pivot column" Value as value, with advanced option (dont aggregate)

[image]

Select "Country" and fill down:

[image]

Finally result:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\YourUser\Downloads\pivot.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"CharacteristicsID", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}, {"Value", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Index", List.Distinct(#"Added Index"[Type]), "Type", "Value"),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Pivoted Column",{"Country"})
in
    #"Filled Down"
```

Comment: Great solution @msta42a. The pivot after the index was the trick. Final step is to take the null rows out on SalesPerson. This is easy done by selecting the dropdown "SalesPerson" and uncheck the null.

Comment: Thank you guys. This really helped! But if you don't mind, I'd ask additional question. Imagine now, that we'll need to add 2 extra columns into my dataset - DateFrom ; DateEnd. E.g. ID = 2 will now have two rows for SalesPerson as in original post, but also 2 rows for Country, one will be US from 01/01/2000 to 31/12/2000 and second UK from 01/01/2001 until 31/12/2022. What do you think? THANKS!